# How do I create an associative array from dynamic variables in php?

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, associative

I have this code:

```
$people=array();
$i=0;
foreach ($xml->xpath('//person') as $character) {
if ($character->status!="Active"){

  $people[$i]['fullname']=(string)$character->fullname;
  $people[$i]['status']=(string)$character->status;
  $i++;

    }
}
```

It creates an array with numeric keys, based on the value of $i. However, I don't actually want that, I want the "fullname" string to be the key but I can't work out how to dynamically assign the key. I was trying things like:

```
$people[(string)$character->fullname]=>(string)$character->status;
```

but this just throws errors. I can't work out how to create keys based on variables. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: What errors does it throw? It certainly looks like it should work. You don't even need the `(string)` casts.

Comment: Does it have to be converted to a string?

Comment: Doh. As the answers below say, you need to change `=>` to `=`.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I now have it working, thanks for your help.

Comment: I see you're a new user here. Welcome! You also may want to take a look at the faq as soon as you find the time.

Comment: what worked for you? I see people answered it is been years

Answer (score 7):

Try this again, but with `=`, not `=>`:

```
$people[ (string) $character->fullname ] = (string) $character->status;
```

Answer (score 1):

You only use `=>` in the Array definition. Otherwise just use bog-standard assignment:

```
$people[$character->fullname] = $character->status;
```

You don't need the casts, as you already have strings. Even if you didn't, you could simply rely on the dynamic typing to convert them as needed on output.

Comment: @Tomalak "Why are they not strings in the first place?" Because he's working with XML. They are nodes, but sometimes you need the *node value*, so you cast to string.

Comment: @Alin: You shouldn't ever have to use explicit casts in a dynamically typed language. The type can be inferred when he gets to use the array elements.

Comment: Alin - yes, I was having some weird issues when I tried to sort before specifically turning them to strings.

Comment: @Max: Ah, you didn't say anything about sorting! Add the casts back in then.

Comment: @Tomalak You can run in all sort of issues if you keep the full objects. You may run out of memory. Sorting may not work as expected. And one I encountered a lot of times is saving the information in the session, XML objects don't serialize. As for casting the objects used as the array index, that is redundant, but in coding a certain amount of redundancy increases readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
$people[$character->fullname] = (string)$character->status;
```